# implement pagination REST API using mongoDB and express.js

Tags: mongodb, express, pagination

I have four collection `mixed, organic, upcycle, vegan`
and these have all same fields like that:

```
// scheme
    const productsSchema = new Schema({
        _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        kind: {
            "upcycle": Boolean,
            "organic": Boolean,
            "vegan": Boolean
        },
        koLCategory: String,
        enLCategory: String,
        sCategory: String,
        koBrandName: String,
        enBrandName: String,
        productName: String,
        thumbNail: String,
        originPrice: String,
        discountPrice: String,
        url: String,
        soldout: Boolean
    });

    const mixedModel = products_conn.model('products', productsSchema, 'mixed');
    const organicModel = products_conn.model('products', productsSchema, 'organic');
    const upcycleModel = products_conn.model('products', productsSchema, 'upcycle');
    const veganModel = products_conn.model('products', productsSchema, 'vegan');

    module.exports = {
        mixedModel,
        organicModel,
        upcycleModel,
        veganModel
    };
```

What I want to do is making pagination REST API.
This code is just implementing REST API (not pagination)

```
router.route('/category/outer/all').get((req, res) => {
    const upcycle = upcycleModel.aggregate([
        {"$match": {"soldout": false, "koLCategory": "keyword"}},
        {"$project":
            {
                "_id": 0,
                "soldout": 0,
            }
        }
    ]);
    const organic = organicModel.aggregate([
        {"$match": {"soldout": false, "koLCategory": "keyword"}},
        {"$project":
            {
                "_id": 0,
                "soldout": 0,
            }
        }
    ]);
    const vegan = veganModel.aggregate([
        {"$match": {"soldout": false, "koLCategory": "keyword"}},
        {"$project":
            {
                "_id": 0,
                "soldout": 0,
            }
        }
    ]);
    const mixed = mixedModel.aggregate([
        {"$match": {"soldout": false, "koLCategory": "keyword"}},
        {"$project":
            {
                "_id": 0,
                "soldout": 0,
            }
        }
    ]);
    Promise.all([
        upcycle,
        organic,
        vegan,
        mixed
    ]).then(data => res.json({
            product: {
                totalCnt: data[0].length + data[1].length + data[2].length + data[3].length,
                items: data[0].concat(data[1]).concat(data[2]).concat(data[3])
            }
        })).catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```

In this case, how can I generate REST API pagination?
Pushing all data in one collection and just using `skip, limit` is very simple, I know.
But I separated collection based on category value for managing data more efficiently.
Is there a solution except pushing all data in one collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem on my own,
the code is:

```
router.route('/category/outer/all/:page').get((req, res) => {
    const upcycle = upcycleModel.aggregate([
        {"$match": {"soldout": false, "koLCategory": "keyword"}},
        {"$project":
            {
                "_id": 0,
                "soldout": 0,
            }
        }
    ]);
    const organic = organicModel.aggregate([
        {"$match": {"soldout": false, "koLCategory": "keyword"}},
        {"$project":
            {
                "_id": 0,
                "soldout": 0,
            }
        }
    ]);
    const vegan = veganModel.aggregate([
        {"$match": {"soldout": false, "koLCategory": "keyword"}},
        {"$project":
            {
                "_id": 0,
                "soldout": 0,
            }
        }
    ]);
    const mixed = mixedModel.aggregate([
        {"$match": {"soldout": false, "koLCategory": "keyword"}},
        {"$project":
            {
                "_id": 0,
                "soldout": 0,
            }
        }
    ]);
    /* this part */
    const page = req.params.page;
    const limit = 30;
    const startIndex = (page - 1) * limit;
    const endIndex = page * limit;
    Promise.all([
        upcycle,
        organic,
        vegan,
        mixed
    ]).then(data => {
        result = data[0].concat(data[1]).concat(data[2]).concat(data[3]).slice(startIndex, endIndex);
        res.json({
            product: {
                totalCnt: result.length,
                items: result
            }
        })
    }).catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```

If you have any more efficient solution, please leave comments.